# Is there any dialect of English with clusivity?

Tags: english, pronouns, clusivity

What it says on the tin. The closest thing that I'm aware of is in Tok Pisin, a creole language which involved English in its creation, which distinguishes “we without you” (*mipela*) from “we with you” (*yumipela*). Is there any variety of English proper that introduced the same distinction?

Comment: 1st plural inclusive in Tok Pisin is _yumipela_, not 'miyupela'. And it's a creole, not an impure variety of English!

Comment: Thanks for a Tok Pisin correction! I edited the question appropriately, both to fix the error and to emphasise the fact that I only involve Tok Pisin as an example of what I'm looking for, not an answer.